# Connecting android app to node js server

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

First time I am trying to connect my android app to node js server (on local system), but its not getting connected. I am trying this from last 15 days but not getting fruitful result.
Here is my code, please have look and provide me with solution(s).

This is the main activity code to connect to server

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try {
        SocketIO socket = new SocketIO("My_System_IP:3000/");
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Server said:" + json.toString(2));
                    // display("Connectet  and " + json.toString(2));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("Server said: " + data);
                // display("Connectet  and " + data);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("an Error occured");
                Log.d("error", "an error occured");
                // display("not Connectet == error occured ");
                socketIOException.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection terminated.");
                Log.e("disconnect", "Connection terminated");
                // display("disConnectet ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                System.out.println("Connection established");
                Log.v("connect", "Connection established");
                // display("Connectet  and done");
            }

            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out
                        .println("Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
                Log.v("ON", "Server triggered event '" + event + "'");
                // display("Connectet  and " + event);
            }
        });

        // This line is cached until the connection is establisched.
        socket.send("Hello Server!");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Here is the IOcallback class code

```
  public interface IOCallback {

/**
 * On disconnect. Called when the socket disconnects and there are no further attempts to reconnect
 */
void onDisconnect();

/**
 * On connect. Called when the socket becomes ready so it is now able to receive data
 */
void onConnect();

/**
 * On message. Called when the server sends String data.
 *
 * @param data the data.
 * @param ack an {@link IOAcknowledge} instance, may be <code>null</code> if there's none
 */
void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack);

/**
 * On message. Called when the server sends JSON data.
 *
 * @param json JSON object sent by server.
 * @param ack an {@link IOAcknowledge} instance, may be <code>null</code> if there's none
 */
void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack);

/**
 * On [Event]. Called when server emits an event.
 *
 * @param event Name of the event
 * @param ack an {@link IOAcknowledge} instance, may be <code>null</code> if there's none
 * @param args Arguments of the event
 */
void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args);

/**
 * On error. Called when socket is in an undefined state. No reconnect attempts will be made.
 *
 * @param socketIOException the last exception describing the error
 */
void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException);
 }
```

And this code other codes are take from [this](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/tree/master/src/io/socket) source available on github.

please help me out to fix this thing, when I running this code its giving one error
        "an error occured"
I attached snapshot on error [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51157895/error_nodejs.JPG)

Server side nodejs code is

```
var http = require('http');
 io      = require('socket.io');
 var app = http.createServer();
 app.listen(3000);

 console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:3000/');

 // Socket.IO server
  var io = io.listen(app)
  , nicknames = {};

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('user message', function (msg) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('user message', {user: socket.nickname, message: msg.message});
  });

  socket.on('nickname', function (nick, fn) {
  nickname = nick.nickname;
  if (nicknames[nickname]) {
   fn(true);
  } else {
   fn(false);
  nicknames[nickname] = socket.nickname = nickname;
  socket.broadcast.emit('announcement', {user: nickname, action: 'connected'});
  io.sockets.emit('nicknames', nicknames);
 }
 });

 socket.on('disconnect', function () {
  if (!socket.nickname) return;

delete nicknames[socket.nickname];
socket.broadcast.emit('announcement', {user: socket.nickname, action: 'disconected'});
socket.broadcast.emit('nicknames', nicknames);
 });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your error?? post your error stack..

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/51157895/error_nodejs.JPG   This is shown in error stack.

Comment: @Subhuraj : Did you get what is my problem ??

Comment: there is a library ready for you to use, https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java

Comment: @Tim : That library is giving error.. i followed step describe there on link you mentioned, But Its gave error that SocketIO class not found.

Comment: @AnkitKumar i not sure, make sure u have all the depenceny!
i have no problem using it